# Changing an Odl file by adding a new method using the add method wizard

Tags: mfc, activex

Here is my problem:

1- I have an activeX project in which I need to add a method to be exposed to the user of my library.
 2- I added my method throw the add method wizard in the .odl file.
 3- I compiled the odl file as requested.
 4- I compiled the activeX project.
 5- I unregistered then registered the activeX in my machine.
--> my new method didn't appear in the list of exposed methods.

I searched and I found that what I did is the correct way to add a method to the odl file.
I don't find a solution for my problem, please help.

PS: I did the same for an activeX that has an IDL file and it works. what is the difference between both types( idl vs odl) ?